# How can I use the directory of a target's output file in CMake commands?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I noticed that when I open my cmake project in Visual Studio 2022, VS create a build directory at `<project_directory>\out\build\x64-Debug` when I choose x646-debug build configuration. When I build the project, the output executable (along with the required DLL files) is written to the build directory itself.

However, if I open the same project i Visual Studio Code, the cmake extension create a build directory at `<project_directory\build`, which is totally fine. When I build, the extension use `cmake --build` command to do the build, and the output is written to the `<project_directory>\build\Debug`.

Which is still fine.

Now I have to add a custom target to copy files from the source directory to the same directory (or subdirectory of that one). I'm currently using `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` which seems to work when working with Visual Studio 2022, but it breaks when building using `cmake --build`. I tried to append `$<CONFIG>` to that variable and now it work in `cmake --build` but breaks in Visual Studio 2022.

So is there any variable that I can use to find the output path of the build?

Below is my current `CMakeLists.txt`. I believe it still contains some other problems, but please pay them no mind for now.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
  CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")

# set the project name
project(sdl2-gl-project-template)

# add the executable
add_executable(main 
    "main.cpp" 
    "scene.hpp" "scene.cpp" 
    "io_util.hpp"
    "shader.hpp" "shader.cpp")

find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(imgui CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gl3w CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(glm CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(spdlog CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(fmt CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(imguizmo CONFIG REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE 
    SDL2::SDL2 
    SDL2::SDL2main 
    OpenGL::GL
    imgui::imgui
    imguizmo::imguizmo
    unofficial::gl3w::gl3w 
    spdlog::spdlog 
    spdlog::spdlog_header_only
    fmt::fmt
    fmt::fmt-header-only)

target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

if (MSVC)
    # set_property(TARGET main PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON)
    target_compile_options(main PRIVATE /Zc:__cplusplus)
endif()

function(compile_shaders)
    set(oneValueArgs TARGET TARGET)
    set(multiValueArgs TARGET INPUT)
    set(oneValueArgs DESTINATION DESTINATION)

    cmake_parse_arguments(COMPILE_SHADERS "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}"
            "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN}
            )

    file(GLOB GLSL_SOURCE_FILES ${COMPILE_SHADERS_INPUT})

    add_custom_target(${COMPILE_SHADERS_TARGET}
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${COMPILE_SHADERS_DESTINATION}/"
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${GLSL_SOURCE_FILES} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${COMPILE_SHADERS_DESTINATION}/"
            )
    add_dependencies(main ${COMPILE_SHADERS_TARGET})
endfunction()

compile_shaders(
        TARGET CompileBasicShader
        DESTINATION "shaders/frag"
        INPUT "shaders/shader.vert" "shaders/shader.frag"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're observing this behaviour is because multi-config generators append a per-configuration directory to the output directory of a target. See for example, [the docs for `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html).

If you want to copy something to a directory based on the directory containing a target's output file in a way that handles that multi-config generator behaviour, use [the `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:tgt>` generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:TARGET_FILE_DIR).

The context where you use it has to support generator expressions of course. For example, `add_custom_target`- which you are using- does. [Its docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) state:

> Arguments to `COMMAND` may use [`generator expressions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html). Use the `TARGET_FILE` generator expression to refer to the location of a target later in the command line (i.e. as a command argument rather than as the command to execute).
>
> Whenever one of the following target based generator expressions are used as a command to execute or is mentioned in a command argument, a target-level dependency will be added automatically so that the mentioned target will be built before this custom target (see policy [`CMP0112`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0112.html#policy:CMP0112)).

Ex.

```
add_custom_target(${COMPILE_SHADERS_TARGET}
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy ${GLSL_SOURCE_FILES} "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${COMPILE_SHADERS_TARGET}>"
)
```